# Android 9 issue: androidx.compose.ui.platform.ViewLayer cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, androidx

We have a crash in our reporting that only happens on Android 9 devices. The stack trace is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.compose.ui.platform.ViewLayer cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:503)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1758)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1701)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:488)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:205)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6993)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:884)
```

It does not indicate which part of our own code causes the problem. Therefore, I don't know which action is required to reproduce it. Reading through the code of FragmentStateManager also did not help much.

The crash happens several thousand times a day for an application with several million active users. 99.97% of the crashes are on Android 9, the rest is on Android 10 (and maybe very few on Android 12, could be fake/wrong data though). The other statistics are not suspicious.

The app uses androidx.fragment:1.4.1 and androidx.compose:1.3.1.

I don't have a good idea where to start searching for the problem and what could cause it. Any hint is welcome.